# how to play sound from Assets in windows universal app

Tags: c#, audio, mediaelement, win-universal-app

I added sounds to assets in project.shared and I added `MediaElement` in the XAML page.

I want to play sound when image is tapped.

And this is my code but it didn't work.

```
</Grid>
    <GridView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-10,-10,10,10" Height="260" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Animals/cat.png" Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Image_Tapped"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Cat" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GridView>
    <MediaElement  Name="AudioPlayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="297,290,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Visibility="Collapsed" Volume="1"/>
</Grid>
```

and this is my event handler

```
private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cat.play();
}
```

Comment: What is the `cat` in `cat.play();`? It is not declared in the XAML.

Comment: Also you should handle the [`MediaFailed` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed.aspx) of the `MediaElement`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define the Source file. You can even add that in the XAML properties of your MediaElement, by adding

Source="mediafile.mp3"

to the  line.

Secondly, the name of your MediaElement is "AudioPlayer", so from the event handler you should call

AudioPlayer.Play();

instead of cat.play();